# Elastic Search 5.0 and scroll api on aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm using the elastic search 5 version and I want to use scroll API like here ([doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/scroll-api.html)) but I have to use it on aggregation. I have a query:

```
GET data/_search?scroll=2m
{
  "aggs": {
    "values"" {
      "terms": {
        "field": "currency",
        "size": 4
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...and I get:

```
{
  "_scroll_id": "1234...a_lot_of_signs..."
  ...
  "hits": [...],
  "aggregations": {
    "values": {
      ...
      "buckets": [
         {
           "key": "EUR",
           "doc_count": 300
         },
         {
           "key": "YEN",
           "doc_count": 300
         },
         {
           "key": "USD",
           "doc_count": 300
         }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

...which gives me first free currencies. I want to get the next 3 currencies so I'm using:

```
GET _search/scroll
{
  "scroll_id": "<id>",
  "scroll": "2m"
}
```

and gets:

```
{
  "_scroll_id": "next_id"
  ...
  "hits": [...]
}
```

So, there are no results for my aggregation which I need. Is there a way to get next currencies?

Answer (score 0):

You always get aggregations for the whole data, not only the `hits` you get back. That's why it makes sense to use `"size": 0` if you *only* need aggregations: you get no `hits` back but all the aggs.

Comment: Where should I add `"size": 0`? I tried adding it to the beginning of the query but till get no results for aggregation when used _search/scroll

Comment: `_scroll` only applies to `hits`, not aggregations. You always get complete aggregation results for the whole dataset with the very first query.